# cross join with a table with single row

Tags: postgresql, cross-join

My `table1` has 25,000+ rows and `table2` has only 1 row. Both of them have almost 30 columns. I need to add all the columns in `table2` (which has only one row) to the columns in `table1` so I can do further calculations. One way to do it is

```
select * from table1 cross join table2
```

It gives the desired results but the performance is not good.

I am wondering if there is a better or faster way to get the combined table. I am using PostgreSQL

Here is the output from

```
explain analyze select * from table1 cross join table2

Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..195264.90 rows=15533650 width=336) (actual time=0.013..46.189 rows=25465 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on table1  (cost=0.00..1076.65 rows=25465 width=232) (actual time=0.007..6.912 rows=25465 loops=1)
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..19.15 rows=610 width=104) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=25465)
       ->  Seq Scan on table2  (cost=0.00..16.10 rows=610 width=104) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)

Planning time: 0.153 ms

Execution time: 50.868 ms
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please. Or upload the plan to https://explain.depesz.com

Comment: Is the query substantially slower than `SELECT * FROM table1`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: edited the question. I believe this is what you wanted  .

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: The actual query is taking ~2.5 times longer than just querying `table1`

Comment: The optimizer thinks that table2 contains 610 rows. Run `analyze table2;` (or `vacuum analyze table2;`) and then check the plan again

Comment: What performance are you expecting?  50ms for 25,000 rows and 60 columns seems pretty good to me.  Is the real issue actually the transmission time to deliver all the results to the client and/or rendering in the client (which I expect is substantially larger than 50ms)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: the performance increased a little bit. It went down from 16s to 11s.

Comment: Then you are losing a lot of time _transferring_ (and displaying) the rows. Because the query only takes 50 **milli**seconds on the server, not 11 seconds.